# "How to limit the function call for all users except those who have a special token with the address 'X'?"

Tags: solidity, tokens, storage, data

hi i'm continuing to explore solidity. I wrote a contract which contains 4 functions: addAuthorizedAddress, removeAuthorizedAddress, storeData, retrieveData. The last two: storeData and retrieveData are for saving and removing data in the contract and can only be called from addresses stored in the authorizedAddresses list in which addresses can only be added by the contract owner. I want to write the contract so that functions addAuthorizedAddress, removeAuthorizedAddress can be called from any addresses where there are special tokens with the contract address "X" But at the same time to add or remove was possible only from the address from which the function addAuthorizedAddress or removeAuthorizedAddress is called. What are possible implementations of such functionality and how to do it best?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: AGPL
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

// Contract Definition
contract DataStorage {

    // Owner address
    address private owner;

    // Addresses that can call contract functions
    mapping(address => bool) private authorizedAddresses;

    // Data structure
    struct Data {
        string dataType;
        string data;
    }

    // Mapping to store data by type
    mapping(string => mapping(address => Data)) private dataByType;

    // Contract constructor
    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    // Modifier to check that the function is called only by the contract owner
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can call this function");
        _;
    }

    // Modifier to check that the function is called only by an authorized address
    modifier onlyAuthorized() {
        require(authorizedAddresses[msg.sender], "Not authorized");
        _;
    }

    // Function to add an authorized address
    function addAuthorizedAddress(address _address) public onlyOwner {
        authorizedAddresses[_address] = true;
    }

    // Function to remove an authorized address
    function removeAuthorizedAddress(address _address) public onlyOwner {
        authorizedAddresses[_address] = false;
    }

    // Function to store data
    function storeData(string memory dataType, string memory data) public onlyAuthorized {
        dataByType[dataType][msg.sender] = Data(dataType, data);
    }

    // Function to retrieve data
    function retrieveData(string memory dataType, address userAddress) public view returns (string memory) {
        return dataByType[dataType][userAddress].data;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what your trying to do here. Any holders of a token can authorize addresses instead of the contract being ownable? Also, what type of token, ERC721, non fungible?

Comment: What do you mean by "But at the same time to add or remove was possible only from the address from which the function addAuthorizedAddress or removeAuthorizedAddress is called" ?

Comment: @Bruce I mean that the function should only accept its own address from which it is called

Comment: @Bruce calling the addData function can only be called from authorized addresses, but you can only authorize your own address and only holders of a specific token. you can make the function paid, but not ETH but ERC20 tokens with a specific contract address should be accepted for payment